# Why there is no definite article?

Tags: definite-article

> *Shipwrecked* on a desert island, coconuts and *other fruits* formed the basis of *the sailors*' diet.

This is from the SAT exam. The problem is that the word *shipwrecked* is misplaced, but it is not the point.

I can't understand why it is *other fruits* and not *the other fruits*. The island, obviously, didn't have all fruits present, but some group of them; that's why *the other fruit* would refer to "the fruits that grew at the island."

Later you have '*the* sailors', a similar situation, but now with *the*.

Comment: Wouldn't _the_ in _the sailors_ simply indicate that we are talking about the _shipwrecked_ sailors, i.e. a specific group of sailors, not sailors that just happen to live on the island?

Comment: *other fruits* without the article implies *other fruits* in general and the author does not want to emphasize exactly which fruits. That's **out of the context** of those particular fruits being found in the desert island.

Comment: @MaulikV I have something to say about this sentence. This sentence is understandable, but I think from grammatical point of view this sentence is incorrect due to "shipwrecked". Please comment on that.

Comment: @snailplane Exactly that is what my point it.

Comment: @Man_From_India Sure...I agree the placement is not that good and Graduate already knows about it. Maybe, we introduce a new term - dangling verb! haha

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Shipwrecked on a desert island, coconuts and other fruits formed the basis of the sailors' diet.

By saying *the other fruits*, you imply that either *coconuts and all other fruits known to man* were eaten, or *coconuts and all other fruits on the island* were eaten.

Now, it is highly unlikely that the island provided only edible fruits. A lot of fruits are poisonous, foul-tasting, or otherwise unfit for human consumption.

"Other fruits" just implies that the sailors ate other fruits besides coconuts, not "all the other fruits besides coconuts".

*The sailors* simply refers to the specific group of sailors that was shipwrecked on the island, not "sailors in general", but "people who happened to be sailors".

(I will ignore the fact--and you had already noticed it--that the sentence implies the fruits were shipwrecked and then were eaten.)

Answer (score 2):

Are you expected to be able to identify which other fruits they're talking about?  Was the list of other fruits mentioned earlier, for example?  If so, then *the* would be felicitous.

Most likely you **can't** identify which other fruits they are.  They probably weren't introduced to you before this sentence.  As a result, the noun phrase *other fruits* should be indefinite, and it is.

Comment: The sailors were not introduced also.

Comment: @Graduate Then the sentence is not felicitous.  (If it was presented out of context, then you have to imagine a context which would make it felicitous, and the appropriate context here would be that the fruits were *not* previously mentioned but the sailors *were*.)